# this code is supposed to delete duplicate values and delete empty spaces but it is deleting unique values as well

Tags: javascript

this code is supposed to delete duplicate values and delete empty spaces but it is deleting unique values as well.

```
cnt = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < this.fin.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.fin.length; j++) {
        if (this.fin[i] == this.fin[j]) {
            cnt++;
            if (cnt > 1) {
                this.fin[j] = '';
            }
        }
        if (j == this.fin.length - 1) {
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
}
this.ntmtg1 = true;
count = 0;
for (let j in this.fin) {
    if (this.fin[j] == '') {
        this.fin.splice(parseInt(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `fin`? Post that array too

Comment: Need fin array data

Comment: Problem is that splice is splicing too much ... perhaps you need to splice(n, 1) ... you'll also need to fix the splicing loop

Comment: @JaromandaX , he is also maniplulating array on which he is also looping , that's wrong

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out in the answer I posted

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - my guess is, fin is an array, with some duplicated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in simply just one line of code with ES6 feature and **[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** :

```js
var fin = ["Vivek","Vivek","Mak","Nik","Mak","Hir","Hari","Nur","Nik"];

var result = [...new Set(fin)];

console.log("Fin Total :" , fin.length , ", Result Total :" , result.length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if the array needs to be mutated in place rather than assigned a new array :p

Answer (score 1):

your logic is almost correct. The couple of mistakes you did are:-

1. In the for loop in the last part of your code, when you use `for( let i in SomeCollection)` 'i' will be the value and not index in the array. I think you want to access the index and not the value. I think you should use should use traditional for loop like `for(int i =0; i<fin.length;i++)`.
2. You need to use splice with two arguments to delete some value from the array.
   here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

Couple of fixes to your code

1. don't use `for in` if you're going to mutate the array
2. splice with only one argument splices from the index to the end of the array, so add a second argument, the length of the splice

in the code below, I omit `this` for simplicity

Also, I moved were `cnt` is defined, so no `if` condition gymnastics needed to reset it

```js
const fin = [1,3,6,7,3,2,4,5,6,4,3,2,1,4,5];
for (let i = 0; i < fin.length; i++) {
    let cnt = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < fin.length; j++) {
        if (fin[i] == fin[j]) {
            cnt++;
            if (cnt > 1) {
                fin[j] = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < fin.length; i++) {
    if (fin[i] == '') {
        fin.splice(i, 1);
        --i; // we've removed an item
    }
}
console.log(fin);
```

Comment: `const fin` really ? :D

Comment: yes - to prove it is *constantly* the same Array - if it were not, then an error would result

Answer (score -1):

fin:any = ["OMAD","SVAC","SVCH","SVAD","LGAG","OMAM","OTBK","OTBH","LGAX","LGBL","SVAN","LGAD","SVAB","SKAP","LGRX","SVAA","SVAS","DNAS","EGEI","NCAT","SVBS","SVBL","SVFM","EPKG","OBBB","OBBS","OBKH","LTFD"
              ,"SVBC","SVBI","SVBM","SVBB","SVBO","TNCB","SVBZ","SKBU","SKBN","SVCI","SVCD","SVCL","SVCN","SVCC","SVCS","SVCO","SVCZ","SKGO","SVCP","NZCG","SVQM","SVCA","LGSA","MWCB","CYCK","SVCB","SVPI","MRCU","EKCN"
              ,"SVCR","SKCV","SVUR","SVCU","SVRB","TNCF","TNCC","LGTT","VRMD","OMDW","SVLL","SVED","SVRS","SVEM","SVJI","SVVG","LGEL","SVEZ","NZEV","EDTF","SVFT","VRMR","SKGB","SVGU","SVGD","SVGT","SVGI","SVQJ","EKHM"
              ,"SVQF","LSPK","SVQL"];

Comment: Suggest you put this in the QUESTION, in a readable format - though, anyone can guess that `fin` is an array with some duplicated values. So, I wouldn't worry about your fellow countrymen asking for the array :p